# How to sync matlab online files to computer?

Tags: matlab, synchronization

I have worked on my MATLAB coding using MATLAB online, and would like to transfer it to my laptop. However, I am unable to find a button to sync it. Is this possible to be done? If not it would be extremely difficult to have to keep copying and pasting all the individual functions each time i work on matlab online and matlab on the software itself.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, syncing of files between MATLAB Online and Desktop MATLAB or any other platforms is not possible as of now. MathWorks may roll out a Dropbox-like solution for MO-Desktop MATLAB syncing some time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [MATLAB Drive](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-drive.html) which was developed exactly for that.

Yet I wish MATLAB Online had a full GIT capabilities (Pulling from GIT Repositories and pushing to them).

Comment: Yes, MATLAB Drive will support you to share files between MATLAB Mobile, MATLAB Online and MATLAB Parallel Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I am uncertain of when this was released, but MathWorks now supplies MATLAB Drive Connector, which operates similarly to Google Drive and Dropbox (automatically!):

https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-drive.html#matlab-drive-connector